# Creating VM from existing installed Windows XP

Tags: vmware-workstation

Is there a way to create new VM from HD with already pre installed Windows XP on it?
I only could find how to install fresh XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends heavily on the virtualizing software you are using. With VMWare its an easy process under normal circumstances and you can do it within the GUI of the software, but with virtualbox for example it requires tinkering and a bit of luck.

edit: Didn't see the tag, if you are using VMWare virtualizing platform you are in luck: https://www.vmware.com/products/converter.html

More info: https://www.howtogeek.com/213145/how-to%C2%A0convert-a-physical-windows-or-linux-pc-to-a-virtual-machine/

Comment: Great! I'll check it.